# How to access SSAS deployment log?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, ssas, business-intelligence, sql-server-data-tools

By mistake, I added a new `calculated member` with the same name as an existing `calculated member`. It added the new calculation without warning.

When I process and deploy I get an error that it failed deployment but no errors or warnings are displayed. I closed VS, restarted the SSAS service, restarted the physical server, but I got the same error. I tried browsing the LOG folder (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS13.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Log), but still didn't find anything related to deployments.

After troubleshooting (ie. looking at the DSV, checking connections, and finally deleting all calculations until finding the issue), I finally realized it was a duplicated calculated member.

Was there an easier way to find the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and found the error in the FlightRecorder in the Log folder:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS13.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Log\FlightRecorderBack.trc

Mine was failing due to having domain users that were no longer valid as members in one of the roles.